# History data of all domains hosted on a given IP

Tags: ip, reverse, lookup

Does somebody know how to check what websites have been hosted on a given IP? Is there any tool that checks this?

I have found several websites that provide Reverse IP Lookup but as far as I know, this gets what domains are currently hosted on the IP. And I want to check historically what the IP has been used for.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no such thing AFAIK.

Comment: https://www.domainiq.com/reverse_ip_history# appears to be what you're looking for, but it is a paid service.